# What materials should I use/avoid when making homemade batteries?

Tags: batteries

Specifically, I don't want anything that might explode in my face or something. It's a simple question, what materials should I use and what ones should I avoid? The use doesn't matter, the end goal doesn't matter, any other information that is not telling me materials I should or should not use to make homemade batteries is useless to me. Every time I post a question on this site people do this... This must be the third account I've made because people here don't answer questions simply but give you 3 paragraphs of stuff that's not what you asked. And they'll ask you for information they really don't need in order to answer you.

Comment: Making homemade batteries is unlikely to be practical.  That means that this is essentially an amateur chemistry question, not an electrical engineering one, so in addition to being too broad, not really on topic here.

Comment: Avoid everything that could be used to build a battery where you can draw any significant current from, since that could potentially explode.

Comment: "I don't want anything that might explode in my face" - From personal experience I can say that Lithium metal is out.

Comment: You would get a better answer if you tell us (a lot) more about your aims. Is this for learning / fun, to use in practical applications?, How much energy do you want to store / what mAh & voltage etc. | Because batteries store energy all have the prospect to "be energetic" and most use one or more corrosive and/or reactive materials. | You can make nicely modestly useful lead acid batteries. They use corrosive sulphuric acid, poisonous lead and lead compounds and a LA battery of more than trivial capacity can provide a thermally useful (or dangerous) discharge.

Comment: Assuming secondary / chargeable cells: Lithium Ion involves a degree of arcane knowledge, corrosive materials and "vent with flames"failure modes. | NimH can corrosive and energy issues. NiCd also plus Cd is poisonous. | And so on. All have some hazrds - understanding them and dealing with them appropriately is essential in all cases.

Comment: Most of them I suspect.

Comment: THIS **IS** an EE question. A lot of the time people reject questions as "shopping questions" - even thoughh in most such cases it is not the case - **BUT** when someone asks a genuine "how do I make this EE component from first principles" questions it's considered too purist. Give it a chance and see what eventuates.  People may even learn something. It's long occurred to me that some of the small primary coint type cells may well be amenable to DIY manufacture wityh relative ease.

Comment: If you want to make a practical battery, forget it. You wouldn't make your own car, or computer (some people do, for the lolz, but only show it, and drive or surf with the thing they bought). If you want to make a demo battery, then a silver spoon and steel spoon stuck in a lemon are good, or any dissimilar metals in an aqueous solution of something interesting.

Comment: Too slow to answer, again : if you're OK with making a primary battery, see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174127/are-there-any-battery-chemistries-that-can-be-fabricated-at-home/174173#174173

Comment: The practicality of this isn't the question, the question is about materials I should or should not use. That does not require any knowledge about the purpose of use to answer. Lead acid batteries also explode, so that's obviously out of the question entirely. The question is simple, what materials should I use or avoid? I really don't care what the amps are or the practicality or any other useless information that has nothing to do with my question, but thanks for your interest. Simple questions require simple answers.

Comment: @DarrylKinslow See exploded battery picture on my answer. You can manage to do something vaguely similar with ANY battery of substantial energy & power delivery capability. Making a battery safe may also make it usefless for your purpose, depending what your purpose is. | I had nothing to do with your question being put on hold but you had a lot to do with it and it could have been avoided. They will only take it off "hold" if you address the points various people  have raised, if then - not something the system handles well, alas. | The obvious source of a generic answer to your question is

Comment: ... [here**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=battery+materials&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig1bivssbQAhXMJ5QKHfZUB_gQsAQIUg&biw=1344&bih=736&dpr=1.25) with each image linking to a related page. || [**THIS TABLE**](http://www.structx.com/Material_Properties_001.html) gives you a vast range of choices. many may be impractical but that's not of concern to you. Take any 2 of these and add an electrolyte and you get some sort of battery with voltage ~~~= the difference between the two numbers shown.

Comment: (1) If you want our answers, you have to be patient with us patiently questioning you.  Alternatively, you can go to a library and read a book: if a book questions you [mind you, that would be a good book], you'll be less upset about that.

Comment: (2) Opening new accounts here will not help you in any way, as you have already noticed.

Answer (score 5):

As Chris said "Making homemade batteries is unlikely to be practical."
Practicality is NOT the only reason to do anything - but in this case 
you would get a better answer if you tell us (a lot) more about your aims. Is this for learning / fun, to use in practical applications?, How much energy do you want to store / what mAh & voltage etc, portable or stationary, rechargeable or single use?, ... . |

IF you really wish to avoid the possibility of explosion then,

- As PlasmaHH said "... everything that could be used to build a battery where you can draw any significant current from could potentially explode."
- And as Bruce Abbott notes  "From personal experience I can say that Lithium metal is out."

However, if you want substantial energy capacity the first MUST be accepted and worked with, and in the case of Lithium or other materials, you may have to learn how to safely deal with basically unsafe materials if you want substantial capability.

Because batteries store energy all have the prospect to "be energetic" and most use one or more corrosive and/or reactive materials.

Assuming secondary / chargeable cells:

- You can make nicely modestly useful lead acid batteries.
  But they use corrosive Sulphuric acid, poisonous lead and lead compounds and a LA battery of more than trivial capacity can provide a thermally useful (or dangerous) discharge.
- Lithium Ion involves a degree of arcane knowledge, corrosive materials and "vent with flames"failure modes.
- NimH entails corrosive and energy issues.
- NiCd as for NimH but in addition Cd is poisonous.

And so on.
**All** have some hazards - understanding them and dealing with them appropriately is essential in all cases.

So - tell us more about what you are trying to achieve.

---

**Lead Acid battery explosion:**

Genuine unedited photosof a lead-acid car battery which 'exploded' while being charged in October this year (2016). This belongs/(ed) to my nephew. I copied these photos from his facebook page. The explosion was probably caused by ignition of Hydrogen gas generated while charging.

This is NOT a common occurrence with lead acid batteries - but certainly happens (as can be seen :-(). If charged and used correctly this is almost certain not to happen. I think that what probably happened here is that it was an old battery with one or more cells that would not take charge and would not reach the usuaul end point voltage. In attempting to charge the battery to the desired end point voltage the charger grossly overcharged the good cells so that they began to generate Hydrogen gas by electrolysis. The gas was then ignited either by gross battery overheating which either caused ignition, or warped a cellcausing an electrical short or by an external source. Either way ... .

[image]

---

**Energy & confinement:**

You MUST assume that  any material that you are using as a chemical energy store + chemical to electrical converter (aka a battery) has the potential [groan]  to liberate energy rapidly and potentially harmfully. I have not yet a battery with more than trivial energy capacity  where this assumption is false.

Many many decades ago (OK - about 50 years ago :-) ) friends and I used to make "things that go bang".  We got quite good at it.
Our most successful pyrotechnic deflagrant was typically used as a few pinches of "stuff" in a paper drinking straw with a twist of straw either  side of the material. We used to detonate it (and, oh yes, it did detonate) using "Jetex" wick.

If 'activated on a smooth surface the pinch of powder would vanish with a felt overpressure wave and no real sound. With the "compression" provided by the twisted single layer of paper drinking straw it was about as loud as a "thundercracker" or say the bottom ed of a military thunderflash.

I estimate the mass of material as around 30 milligrams and the energy available to probably be somewhere in the  500 -  1500 Joules range. Say 38 or 45 magnum or 10mm pistol area. I am not going to say  what the materials were but of the two main ones, one is very common (but rather  hardercto access now than then) and the other not unknown in commercial and domestic use. [As a bonus one is essentially non-poisonous but can be converted to an extremely dangerouslt poisonous form 'by mistake'.]
If you achieved a material that was even 1% as energetic while "playing" you could distribute 'nasty stuff' over a significant area and into too many eyes (1+ is too many).

**Self assembling self launching rocket (really!)** - I have had random pool chemicals in a plastic bottle 'all by themselves' launch a plastic bottle about 50 feet with enough energy to break plastic roofing.
I never worked out what material did it or how it managed the trick.

Comment: "... everything that could be used to build a battery where you can draw any significant current from could potentially explode." This is quite wrong. A battery which is not sealed is not likely to explode unless it's got explosive or volatile materials. The use doesn't matter and has nothing to do with the question. We're talking about stuff I can find around the house or walking around, not stuff I would need special licencing or chemical knowledge to get my hands on. What I am trying to achieve,  specifically, is getting materials together for making homemeade batteries.

Comment: @DarrylKinslow I went out of my way to provide a starting point that you could build on and perhaps end up with something that would assist your aims but, very sadly, you chose to focus on telling people what they didn't need to know and that what people did tell you was wrong or useless. || The word "detonate" has a precise meaning. Explode is rather more general.  ANY battery that can deliver powers of say 100's of Watts can throw material over a wide area in some cases. I've seen lead acid batteries that exploded by any useful understanding of the term. LiIon batteries specialise in ...

Comment: @DarrylKinslow ... dying in flaming ruin. NimH and NiCd can do very well indeed. || When you find that "This must be the third account I've made because people here ..." then you need to learn things & listen to what you are told OR go to a site where people have few clues, talk rubbish, do not know or care about safety and will happily mislead you and lead you astray. There are lots of these and they are easy to find.  | End use does matter, energy capacity and power levels matter. At present your question is not  much more directed than eg "What materials do I need to make a food?". Alas.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit this Lead Acid battery explosion case?

Comment: @Ayhan The battery was being charged and exploded. It was old and I'd guess that it may have had one or more very low cells which caused the charger to keep supplying current when  the godd cells were fully charged SO it evolved hydrogen, as they do, and something overheated or something nearby ignited the Hydrogen and ... .  It happens.

Comment: Thank you. I am soon to deal with these batteries for renewable energy.

Comment: Useless, all of you. It was a simple question, you can give a simple answer instead of being idiots and asking for information you do not need. All I wanted to know is what materials I can use to make batteries which will not explode in my face. I found out all on my own because none of you idiots would tell me anything and assumed you needed more information to simply tell me "use this material, this material, this material and maybe this material" Whoever had this closed as "too broad" obviously didn't get that all I needed was materials I can make batteries with.

Comment: What I want to use the batteries for, any purpose for making the batteries or anything else has nothing to do with the question. Unless the answer is materials that I can use to make batteries, materials which will not explode in my face, then you didn't answer the question and should not have come here.

Comment: One person out of all the people who came here actually gave me an answer, unfortunately they suggest ni-cd and ni-mh, I wasn't exactly looking for something I can go buy in a store.