# Can you build a battery from scratch which is able to make a computer run?

Tags: batteries, coin-cell

I'm learning about batteries and I'm really fascinated by this topic.
I saw some online videos on how to build some ["Voltaic Pile - like" batteries with coins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIHfUJu3aKo) and other kind of cells in different ways.
The hosts then usually use this batteries to power up simple elctronic devices ( such as flashlights or calculators).
I then saw some videos showing how to [replace computer batteries using industrial cells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrDnTXqoqjM&t=294s)(batteries) in order to rebuild the laptop battery pack.
I was wondering if it's possible to join this 2 processes in someway. Essentially, building some cells (single batteries) from scratch and arranging them together in order to create a laptop battery pack.
I don't know if anyone knows about someone who did it and can link them to me.
I did not find anything like that, and I'm starting to think that If it's not impossible, it is at least very complicated.
Anyway, I don't have the skill and the experience to understand where the complexity actually is, so that's why I'm asking it.

Comment: Would it really be worth the time and effort? Or is this just a science project?

Comment: Probably not. But It would make me understand a lot. I love this kind of things! :)

Comment: http://batteryuniversity.com/ Enjoy.

Comment: Batteries use very toxic dielectrics and your MSDS skills must be good. e.g. acids or bases in order to get high ionic concentrations. so high capacity and low ESR is not easy

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yeah probably I don't have the experience required.....But if I manage to see someone getting  it done, It would be inspiring and motivating

Comment: This one might... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174127/are-there-any-battery-chemistries-that-can-be-fabricated-at-home/174173#174173

Comment: @Tyler Honestly, very few projects here will be worth the time and effort. :)

Comment: Failures in insulation or foil separation results in fire or worse if it really high energy density.  http://www.mtixtl.com/li-ionbatterychemicalpowdersbindersandelectrodessheet.aspx

Comment: So, use lemons and copper strips, then you can make some G&T’s as well...

Comment: Running a desktop computer would be hard; but you could probably get a miconcontroller-scale computer to run on a few kitchen chemistry cells.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Would it be that much difference? I was thinking of a laptop btw

Comment: A laptop is going to need 100 to 1000 times as much power as a small MCU.

Comment: @ChrisStratton why not go for a Raspberry Pi.  It's pretty much the minimum that would do things most people recognise as a computer, it's cheap, and [the model zero can get down to 400mW power consumption](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-power)

Comment: A raspberry pi is still quite wasteful, as it lacks the kind of fine grained power control that an MCU or even a faster-than-pi mobile chip has.  Running one on a potentially flakey power supply is also very unwise, as it is a system which requires orderly shutdown to avoid corruption.  With enough effort it is do-able, but it's going to be at least an order of magnitude harder project than getting a little ARM or ATtiny to do some proof-of-concept computing on a few lemons and coins.

Comment: @ChrisStratton [back up the SD card first and don't worry about it](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42647/can-pulling-the-power-cause-any-problem-except-with-the-sd-card-contents). I'd also run it off more cells than strictly necessary with a switching regulator; combined with a voltage divider to a GPIO you could actually implement an orderly shutdown.  Now I really want to know what 400mW is in lemons per hour

Comment: That would likely require more lemons than you can keep reliably operating at one time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it would likely be neither cheap nor compact.

Essentially you would have to

- pick a chemistry
- make a string of sufficient cells in series to provide acceptable input voltage
- make sufficient "strings" to provide adequate output current

You would almost certainly want to pick a rechargeable chemistry, which suggests either lead-acid or NiFe ("Edison"). NiCad is too poisonous and the higher-density lithium ones are too flammable.

There's a community of people building DIY NiFe batteries for use with off-grid renewable energy. Google will show you plans. Or you can look at Edison's original patents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If it eliminates some complexity, it would be enough if they're able to make the computer run even for only a cylce, just to see it working. Probably not the most intelligent approach, but It would be very helpful to me to eliminate some chemistry related complexity :)

Comment: I would also suggest NiFe if you want to make some vaguely useful battery. A more practical project might be NiFe+solar panel+leds = home made solar light. The whole thing lives and works outside, which is where you really want to keep something with wet alkali (or acid). The amount of energy, and required #cells is fairly low. It might be able to run for many years, with just a water top-up now and then, which would be long term, more satisfying that a ran-a-raspberry-pi-once-then-threw-it-away type project. http://www.earthineer.com/blog/29533/the-idiot-edison-battery-diy

Comment: One of the good things about the basic lead-acid and NiFe chemistries is that they have relatively good current delivery for reasonable-sized electrodes.  So as long as your computer is a low-power model, you only need to worry about getting sufficient voltage and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to consider what countsa as the minimal "computer" for this demonstration. I suggest the [Raspberry Pi zero](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/raspberry-pi-zero-power) as its power consumption can get down to 400mW with a bit of effort.  If you back up the SD card before you start you [don't have to worry too much about an ungraceful shutdown](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42647/can-pulling-the-power-cause-any-problem-except-with-the-sd-card-contents).

Then you have to build your battery.  I'd go for a vinegar battery (probably with copper and zinc) as it lends itself more to big electrodes for higher current than some other designs (though you can always connect in parallel).  I'd then power it through a switching regulator like [OKI78SR](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/OKI-78SR-12-10-W36E-C?qs=sGAEpiMZZMt6Q9lZSPl3RQsOIly2NLEkvturMq5XVU51UlX1Pdtx%2fQ==).  This would mean enough cells in series to get more than about 6V loaded; you can test this with a suitable resistor before buying anything expensive.

There are lower power processors out there -- you've probably got one in you pocket -- but this gives you a general purpose computer that does things perople understand a computer to do.  You'd need power for your monitor though (unless you went for a PiTFT or similar, but even then your battery wouldn't last long

Comment: While this is better than a desktop or laptop, it's still unlikely to be practical - you'd need enough cells that it may be hard to  even just have them all working at the same time.

Comment: @ChrisStratton a vinegar battery could easily be scaled up to cells the size of buckets, with large electrodes, hopefully avoiding the need for parallel connections. I'd actually use something like paint roller trays and sheet electrodes with plastic spacers. 4 in series would be enough to provide sufficient headroom for a switching regulator. My Pi is a 2B, which draws quite a bit more, and I only have linear regulators, otherwise I might be tempted to have a go.

Comment: You seem to be either overestimating the potential of a copper zinc cell, or assuming you can run a pi at a lower voltage than the manufacturer's specification.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'd misremembered it as 1.6V. Having checked you'd need 5 or 6 in series as they're apparently 1.1V

Comment: @ChrisStratton Which is the limit of this cells you can have working together at the same time according to you? and What limits this number?

Comment: The limit is reliability of typical kitchen chemistry setups.  Maybe you can beat it, but a pi is a system that really, really doesn't like unexpected power loss.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the answers at the end of my first paragraph suggest otherwise -- at least if you can restore the SD card from a backup.  That's fine for a demo system, and let's face it, we're not talking about more than a demo here.

Comment: Given that you depend on a monitor powered some other way to preserve the public misconception of what a computer is, not really.  There clearly are demonstrably computational systems which can run *with* their UI on kitchen chemistry solutions, which are by their nature quite fine with unexpected power loss - and which can help counteract some of the misconception of what a computer is.

Answer (score 0):

> Voltaic Pile-like batteries

The classic Votaic pile was a stack of many small, low-capacity cells. Relatively high voltage, but not much power.

I'd look to the sort of batteries that powered early Telegraph systems.  I built something like a [gravity cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_battery#Gravity_cell) (a.k.a., "crow's foot cell") when I was a kid in fifth grade. The chemicals are mostly harmless. Never measured how much energy I could get from it, but check out these pages:  https://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/phys/gravity.htm , http://w1tp.com/mbatt.htm .

You can Google for other examples.